# string comparison in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have this function:

```
function GetListByKeywords($keywords) 
{
  $HOST_DB = "localhost";
  $NAME_DB = "jobs";
  $USER_DB = "root";
  $PWD_DB = "";
  $connect = mysql_connect($HOST_DB, $USER_DB, $PWD_DB);
  $db = mysql_select_db($NAME_DB);
  $table = split('[;]', $keywords);
  $Log_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM  employment") or die(mysql_error());
  $p = 0;
  while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query)) {
    $id[$p] = $Res_user;
    $p++;
  }
  $Log_query = mysql_query("SELECT description FROM  employment") or die(mysql_error());
  $p = 0;
  while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query)) {
    $responsabilite[$p] = $Res_user;
    $p++;
  }
  $p = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($table); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < sizeof($responsabilite); $j++) {
      if (strcmp($table[$i], $responsabilite[$j]) > 0) {
        $marques[$p] = $id[$j];
        $p++;
      }
    }

  }
  return $marques;

}
```

i want to compare the string `$keywords` to the fields of `$responsabilite`. so i convert it to the table `$table` and i compare each element by each element in the table responsabilite. so i need a function that can replace `strcmp` because i need to know if the element of `$keywords` exist in the string `$responsabilite[$i]` or not

Comment: Mind taking the effort of formatting the source code?

Comment: strpos function tells you if a string exists in another string. It returns the int position of where the string occurs, so you need to use a strict comparison (i.e. strpos($needle, $haystack) !== false {//it exists})

Comment: thanks Mike but strpos returns int or boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you check if element in one array exist in other array with [array_ intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)